# Когда компилирую код, выдаёт "zip: invalid option -- q"

Tags: python, windows, zip

Изучаю python по книге A byte of python. Компилирую код в консоли Windows. Выдаёт **"zip: invalid option -- q
Использование: zip [ОПЦИЯ]... {только-скрипт-если-нет-другого-скрипта} [входной-файл]..."**

Я удалил с команды `zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))` букву q. После этого мне в консоль выдало : **zip: -e выражение #1, символ 1: неизвестная команда: `C'
Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ**

(Сам код внизу)

"Zip" поместил в PATH

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так-же ещё, zip.exe назывался sed.exe, поэтому я переименовал его на zip.exe.

Нужна помощь.

Код:

```
import os
import time

# Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']

# Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'C:\\Backup'

# Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# Zip-команда
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

Запуск создания резервной копии
print(zip_command)
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Также ещё при создании "второй версии" кода, компилятор выдаёт  **"zip: -e выражение #1, символ 1: неизвестная команда: `C' Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ"**, но, бэкап удаётся, правда не рекурсивно(не передаются под-каталоги)

Код от второй версии:

```
import os
import time
# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.
# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'C:\\Backup' # Подставьте ваш путь.
# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Текущая дата служит именем подкаталога в основном каталоге
today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
# Текущее время служит именем zip-архива
now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')
# Создаём каталог, если его ещё нет
if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today) # создание каталога
    print('Каталог успешно создан', today)
# Имя zip-файла
target = today + os.sep + now + '.zip'
# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
# Запускаем создание резервной копии
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Comment: `Так-же ещё, zip.exe назывался sed.exe, поэтому я переименовал его на zip.exe.` — и пытаетесь вызывать под именем zip.exe совершенно другую программу. вероятно, какую-то из реализаций [sed](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed). вероятно, ту, к которой относится [это описание](http://emulek.github.io/sed/ch03.html)

Comment: Да уж. У меня не было пилы, поэтому я взял молоток, написал на нём «пила», но она почему-то всё равно не пилит? ‍♂️